# Как можно найти в трех массивах одинаковые числа?

Tags: массивы, алгоритм

Как решить эту задачу не прибегая к перебору первого массива относительно второго, второго относительно третьего и первого относительно третьего?

a[ax] , b[bx] , c[cx]  - перебор в лоб даст сложность ax * bx + bx * cx + ax * cx

Comment: Хэш таблица решает эту проблему с потрохами

Comment: Хэширование и есть способ индексирования, то бишь сортировки... Выигрыш будет если только искомая задача решается постоянно (вызывается несколько раз).

Comment: Насчёт сортировки -- это несколько смело.

Comment: @alexlz, в **update 2** моего ответа (там комментарии кончились) добавил результат питона.

Comment: @alexlz подумай ночью и поймешь что я прав насчет сортировки :) Ну или попиши на досуге алгоритм индексирования в каком-нить СУБД

Comment: @Barmaley "подумай ночью"... Настоящий Бармалей. Не буду. Из старых учебников, в главах "сортировка и поиск", хэш-таблицы использовались именно для поиска. Давали в идеале сложность O(1) или чуть хуже (в зависимости от коллизий). О сортировке речь для них не шла, потому как положил значение хрен знает куда, а при поиске проверил -- есть ли оно в этом месте.

Comment: @alexlz, про range я уже понял. Бог с ним, с randint (и randrange, хоть с ним и быстрее). Интересней другое.

--

Я пытался найти, но не нашел, как эффективно строить списки в питоне. Ведь  17 сек. уходит на построение 3-х списков. Причем, это же не random такой медленный.

Может кроме такой красивой записи, генерирующей список, есть что-нибудь (возможно считающееся дубовым), но позволяющее, например, "преаллокировать" элементы?

Я померил, на Си генерация этих массивов выполняется 250 msec. Нет ли в питоне (в Учебник Python 3.1 в вики ничего не нашел) нормальных массивов?

Comment: Так бодрее:  

    from time import clock
    from random import randint
    from numpy import random
    max_int = 2**32-1
    t0 = clock()
    a1=random.uniform(0, max_int, 10000000)
    a2=random.uniform(0, max_int, 2000000)
    a3=random.uniform(0, max_int, 3000000)
    t1 = clock()
    print (t1-t0)
    [b1, b2, b3] = [[randint(0, max_int) for i in range(0, n)] for n  in (10000000, 2000000, 3000000)]
    t2 = clock()
    print (t2-t1)
    a = set(a1) & set(a2) & set(a3)
    t3 = clock()
    print (t3 - t2)

>0.3861997563996409
45.08396043115703
9.143818220108159

Comment: Продолжаю. У @avp как я понял время между start и end не включает время создания HashSet, исключим и мы его из Python дописав еще такие строки:  

    c1, c2, c3 = set(a1), set(a2), set(a3)
    t3=clock()
    print (t3-t2)
    a = c1 & c2 & c3
    t4 = clock()
    print (t4 - t3)
    a= set(a1) & set(a2) & set(a3)
    t5=clock()
    print (t5-t4)

>4.751900382478016  
0.2526530640729696  
8.079792869906981

То есть налицо, что можно ускорить сам код питона вдвое, но и результат поиска только пересечения может потягаться с С++.

Comment: @ReinRaus, время между start и end **включает время создания HashSet**.

Посмотрите в коде 

    long long start = mtime(), end;
    struct htab *ht = intersect(arr); // именно в ней сначала делаем HashSet
    if (ht) {
      end = mtime();
       ...

--

У меня Python 2.7.3 не понимает random.randint(0, max_int, n) - ругается на количество аргументов. 

Вы каким пользуетесь? Лучше все же переносимость, чем новизна.

Итого: если отбросить генерацию массивов, то какое время получилось?

Comment: @avp random из numpy взят, просто некрасивость получилась здесь  

    from random import randint
    from numpy import random

Comment: @avp Вам не ответил, был занят, но ответил @RainRaus. 

Пытался вместо set использовать frozenset (неизменяемые). Улучшений не заметил.

И, поскольку Вы на питоне не пишете, запомните функцию dir() и атрибут `__doc__`, в котором обычно сидит описание класс/функции/etc. Т.е.

     print dir.__doc__

а далее -- по индукции.

Comment: @ReinRaus, в моей Убунте

    sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy

и заработало. Интересная картина (все с numpy)

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./t.py
    randint(0, max_int, n)
    0.15 Generating
    10.08 Intersection
    VmHWM:   846724 kB
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./t.py
    randint(0, max_int)
    2.81 Generating
    3.91 Intersection
    VmHWM:  1035608 kB
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 

К сожалению и здесь последний комментарий, а жаль, тема получилась интересной (заодно чуть к питону приобщился).

И все-таки, если учесть Гиг(!) памяти C и Python вещи разного порядка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет необходимости делать такой сложный перебор:
достаточно выбрать элементы массива1 входящие в массив2, из этого результата выбрать элементы входящие в массив3.
Пример на Python3:

```
>>> arr1=list(range(5,10))
>>> arr2=list(range(8,20))
>>> arr3=list(range(7, 14))
>>> filter1=lambda x: x in arr2
>>> filter2= lambda x: x in arr3
>>> [x for x in [y for y in arr1 if filter1(y)] if filter2(x)] # 1 способ
[8, 9]
>>> [x for x in arr1 if filter1(x) and filter2(x)] # 2 способ
[8, 9]
```

Comment: @avp уже написал про множества.

     a = set(range(5,10))
     b = set(range(8, 20))
     c = set(range(7, 14))
     print (list(a & b & c))

Comment: Пример неправильный, поскольку все равно в питоне реализовано это перебором :) А то что синтаксис не кажет перебор суть не меняется

Comment: @barmaley, да вроде все норм. Код соответствует описанному алгоритму  
> достаточно выбрать элементы массива1 входящие в массив2, из этого результата выбрать элементы входящие в массив3

Answer (score 7):

Поместить их в множество (например HashSet (форум-то как называется?)).

**UPDATE**

Почему-то интересно мне стало, сколько времени будет это работать для миллионов чисел

```
// 3arrays.c avp 2013 linux, gcc/g++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>

/*
  Программка поиска одинаковых чисел в 3-х массивах.

  Размер массивов берем из argv и заполняем их числами rand(),
  заданной величины (если задать 0 - не меняем rand()).
  Описания массивов поместим в вектор (из 3-х элементов) таких структур:
*/
struct array {
  int  size, // размер массива
    *val,    // числа в нем
    num;     // его номер (c нуля) 
};

/*
  Для поиска используем простую достаточно разряженную хэш-таблицу 
  с открытой адресацией и линейным пробированием.
  (http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D1%8D%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

  Ключ - число из массива, данные битовая маска номеров массивов,
  в которых встечается это число.
  Поскольку ищем в 3-х массивах, то достаточно одного байта,
  в старшем бите будем хранить признак, занят ли этот элемент таблицы.
 */
struct htab {
  int size,   // размер таблицы
    nelems,   // количество заполненных элементов в ней
    *key;     // искомые числа
  char *data; // признак занят (старший бит) и маска номеров массивов
};

// вспомогательные функции для печати времени и занятой памяти
long long mtime();
int  pri_mem (int pid, char **what);

// создать массив и заполнить его rand() величиной до maxvalue
static int  *make_array (struct array *pa, int maxvalue);

/*
 Основная функция поиска общих чисел.
 Заполняет хэш-таблицу числами самого короткого массива,
 ищет в ней числа других массивов и проставляет их номера в data[]

 После ее вызова те элементы data[] в таблице, у которых выставлены
 биты номеров всех массивов, соответствуют общим числам key[]
*/
struct htab *intersect (struct array *pa);
// если массив j короче массива i, то переставить их в векторе массивов
static void swap_small (struct array *pa, int i, int j);

// делает пустую хэш-таблицу для arrsize чисел
struct htab *make_htab (int arrsize);
// удаляет данные таблицы и ее саму
void free_htab (struct htab *);
/*
  Добавляет число в хэш, НЕ СТАВИТ номер массива в data[],
  возвращает индекс элемента в таблице
  или -1 (hash-table overflow)
*/
int  add_htab (struct htab *ht, int key);
/*
  Ищет число в хэш-таблице и 
  возвращает индекс в ней или -1 (не нашли)
 */
int  find_htab (struct htab *ht, int key);

// Макросы для работы с хэшем
// элемент присутствует во всех трех массивах
#define INALLARRS(ht,i) (((ht)->data[(i)] & 0x7) == 0x7)

// функция хэширования
#if 1
// хэш код для числа
#define HASHCODE(x,s) ({int h = (x) * 1103515245; if (h < 0) h = -h; h;})
#else
// поскольку у нас числа rand(), то можно так
#define HASHCODE(x,s) (x)
#endif

// элемент хэша уже занят
#define HASHBUSY(ht,i) ((ht)->data[(i)] & 0x80)
// установить элемент хэша в "занято"
#define HSETBUSY(ht,i) ((ht)->data[(i)] |= 0x80)
// просто сравнить искомое число с ключем их таблицы
#define HASHEQUAL(k1,k2) ((k1) == (k2))

// Основная часть для трех массивов
struct htab *
intersect (struct array arr[])
{
  // поместим самый короткий массив в arr[0]
  swap_small(arr, 0, 1);
  swap_small(arr, 0, 2);

  struct htab *ht = make_htab(arr[0].size);
  if (ht) {
    int  i, j, k;

    // занесем числа самого короткого массива в хэш
    for (i = 0; i < arr[0].size; i++) {
      if ((j = add_htab(ht, arr[0].val[i])) < 0) {
        puts("Hash table overflow");
        free_htab(ht);
        return NULL;
      }
      // номер массива в элемент data[], соответствующий числу
      ht->data[j] |= (1 << arr[0].num);
    }

    // ищем числа из остальных массивов в хэше
    for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < arr[i].size; j++) {
        if ((k = find_htab(ht, arr[i].val[j])) >= 0)
          // нашли - занесем номер массива
          ht->data[k] |= (1 << arr[i].num);
      }
    }
  }
  return ht;
}

static void
swap_small (struct array *pa, int i, int j)
{
  struct array t;

  if (pa[i].size > pa[j].size) {
    t = pa[i];
    pa[i] = pa[j];
    pa[j] = t;
  }
}

static int
Usage ()
{
  puts("Intersect random numbers in 3 arrays");
  puts("Usage: 3arrays maxvalue a1-size a2-size a3-size");
  return 1;
}

// отладочная печать
#define PRINT_ARRAY_MAXSIZE 10
static void
print_array (struct array *arr, int i)
{
  printf ("array %d size %d:\n", i, arr[i].size);
  int j;
  for (j = 0; j < arr[i].size; j++)
    printf ("%d ", arr[i].val[j]);
  puts("");
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac != 5 || (av[1] && strcmp(av[1],"-h") == 0))
    return Usage();

  int maxvalue = atoi(av[1]),
    i, n, rc = -1;
  struct array arr[3];

  if (maxvalue < 1)
    maxvalue = 0;
  for (i = 2; i < 5; i++) {
    if ((arr[i-2].size = atoi(av[i])) < 1) {
      printf("Invalid array size [%s]\n", av[i]);
      return rc;
    }
    arr[i-2].num = i-2;
    if (!make_array(&arr[i-2], maxvalue))
      return rc;
  }

  if (arr[0].size <= PRINT_ARRAY_MAXSIZE) {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      print_array(arr, i);
  }

  long long start = mtime(), end;
  struct htab *ht = intersect(arr);
  if (ht) {
    end = mtime();
    puts("elements in all 3 arrays");
    for (i = n = 0; i < ht->size; i++)
       if (INALLARRS(ht,i)) {
        n++;
        printf ("%d\n", ht->key[i]);
      }
    printf ("\n%d elements are equal in 3 arrays (%lld msec)\n", 
            n, end - start);
    const char *what[] = {"vmpeak","vmhwm",NULL};
    pri_mem(getpid(), (char **)what);
    rc = 0;
  }

  free_htab(ht);
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    free(arr[i].val);

  return rc;
}

int *
make_array (struct array *pa, int maxvalue)
{
  pa->val = (typeof(pa->val)) malloc(pa->size * sizeof(*pa->val));
  if (pa->val) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < pa->size; i++)
      pa->val[i] = maxvalue ? rand() % (maxvalue+1) : rand();
  }
  return pa->val;
}

/*
  Функции хэш-таблицы
*/
void
free_htab (struct htab *ht)
{
  if (ht) {
    free(ht->data);
    free(ht->key);
    free(ht);
  }
}

struct htab *
make_htab (int size)
{
  struct htab *ht = (typeof(ht)) malloc(sizeof(*ht));
  ht->nelems = 0;
  ht->size = size * 2;
  ht->key = (typeof(ht->key)) malloc(sizeof(*ht->key) * ht->size);
  int datalen = sizeof(*ht->data) * ht->size;
  ht->data = (typeof(ht->data)) malloc(datalen);
  memset(ht->data, 0, datalen);

  return ht;
}

int
add_htab (struct htab *ht, int key)
{
  if (ht->size - ht->nelems < 1)
    return -1;
  int hc = HASHCODE(key,ht->size),
    i;

  for (i = hc % ht->size; HASHBUSY(ht,i); i = (i+1) % ht->size)
    if (HASHEQUAL(key,ht->key[i]))
      return i;

  ht->key[i] = key;
  HSETBUSY(ht,i); 
  ht->nelems++;
  return i;
}

int
find_htab (struct htab *ht, int key)
{
  int hc = HASHCODE(key,ht->size),
    i;

  for (i = hc % ht->size; HASHBUSY(ht,i); i = (i+1) % ht->size)
    if (HASHEQUAL(key,ht->key[i]))
      return i;
  return -1;
}

/*
  время в миллисекундах
 */
#include <sys/time.h>

long long
mtime()
{
  struct timeval t;

  gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
  long long mt = (long long)t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000;
  return mt;
}

/*
  Печать занимаемой виртуальной памяти 
  выбирает строки для VmPeak, VmHWM и т.п. (задается в what[])

  returns second field for last line selected by  'what'
 */
int
pri_mem (int pid, char **what)
{
  char path[1000];
  int  res = 0;

  sprintf (path,"/proc/%d/status",pid);
  FILE *in = fopen(path,"r");
  if (!in) {
    perror(path);
    return -1;
  }
  while (fgets(path,1000,in)) {
    char **w = what;
    while (*w) {
      if (strncasecmp(path,*w,strlen(*w)) == 0) {
        fputs(path,stdout);
        char dummy[1000];
        sscanf(path,"%s %d",dummy,&res);
        break;
      }
      w++;
    }
  }
  fclose(in);

  return res;
}

avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ -O3 3arrays.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 0 10000000 2000000 3000000
elements in all 3 arrays
1334186
1896006293
1360753284
1810715330
2076667386
716593144
1411086978
285895000
554359395
587503010
1984243435

11 elements are equal in 3 arrays (799 msec)
VmPeak:    82436 kB
VmHWM:     78492 kB
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz

Программка, конечно, не самая короткая получилась.....

Но, интересно, вот код на питоне из нескольких строк ([[@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus)](/users/481/reinraus), [[[[@alexlz](/users/352/alexlz)](/users/352/alexlz)](/users/352/alexlz)](/users/352/alexlz)) сколько исполняется?

**UPDATE 2**

[[[[@alexlz](/users/352/alexlz)](/users/352/alexlz)](/users/352/alexlz)](/users/352/alexlz), вот обещанный прогон Вашего питона.

```
print len(a), ":", a
PID = os.getpid()
os.system('grep -i vmhwm /proc/%s/status' % PID)
```

Это печать, которую я добавил. Еще заменил `max_int` на `2**31-1`, чтобы числа в Си и питоне были теми же. Но, не тут то было, `rand()` и `randint(0, 2**31-1)` выдают разные последовательности.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./t.py
17.22
3.62
20 : set([687951041, 1812116738, 1856480747, 1181177828, 263957894, 655554023, 1712789003, 1663729594, 2008088589, 838062393, 1649222384, 467595281, 1751538846, 1591182070, 1509586873, 1232019449, 32582074, 785746715, 1155483581, 1303719902])
VmHWM:   1027496 kB
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Пришлось добавить памяти (до 2GB), а то сначала все уснуло. Кстати, после добавления памяти почему-то программа на Си заработала медленнее (816-834 msec).

Comment: На Python пишут для души, а не для скорости :)

Comment: так и хочется закричать CUT! :)

Comment: Мда... Наверное, не зря я в последнее время на питон перебрался. Кстати, `numpy` очень даже шустро работает.

Но если уж очень нужна скорость, то можно в С++ с использованием std::set проделать.

Comment: @ReinRaus, не, на питоне пишут для скорости написания.

Comment: @avp, запустил тест с такими же размерами массивов- 10000000, 2000000, 3000000 - ждал около полутора часов и надоело -_-

Comment: @ReinRaus, очевидно здесь дело не в скорости операций в Си и питоне, а в разных алгоритмах.

Интерпретатор "не понимает", что действительно нужно делать (поиск с хэшем или сортировка и согласованный проход по массивам с применением фильтра и т.п.) для получения результата, вид которого так замечательно описан.

Кстати, это было характерно для первых реализаций SQL.

Comment: @avp Уменьшил размеры массивов на порядок. Но. Основное время -- построение множеств. (процессор -- древний Celeron)

   from time import clock
   from random import randint
   max_int = 2**32-1
   t0 = clock()
   [a1, a2, a3] = [[randint(0, max_int) for i in range(0, n)] for n in (1000000, 200000, 300000)]
   t1 = clock()
   print (t1-t0)
   t1 = clock()
   a = set(a1) & set(a2) & set(a3)
   t2 = clock()
   print (t2 - t1)

время 20.05 и 1.77 соответственно. Посмотрите, сколько будет у Вас (а если эти штуки будут активно своп напрягать -- тогда точно уснуть можно)

Comment: @alexlz, вечером на том же компе запущу. А пока на

    model name : Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5400  @ 2.70GHz

    avp@avp-xub11:/tmp$ ./t.py 
    4.11
    0.72

а для 10000000, 2000000, 3000000

    avp@avp-xub11:/tmp$ ./t.py 
    39.84
    9.81

О пэйджинге речь, конечно, не идет.

А как на из питона вызвать grep -i vmhwm  /proc/<PID>/status, чтобы память посмотреть.

Comment: @avp 

      import os
       ....
      f = os.popen('grep -i vmhwm /proc/%s/status' % PID, 'r')

Ну и дальше читаете из f (открытый хэндл)

Но если тип PID -- целое, тогда, конечно, `%d`

Comment: @aleхlz, я на питоне вообще не пишу. Но, за `import os` спасибо

        os.system('grep -i vmhwm /proc/%s/status' % PID)

Это оказалось попроще

    avp@avp-xub11:/tmp$ ./t.py 
    5.52
    1.2
    VmHWM:    70676 kB
    avp@avp-xub11:/tmp$ ./t.py 
    53.75
    15.76
    VmHWM:   617184 kB
    avp@avp-xub11:/tmp$ 

То ли машина чем-то загружена оказалась, то ли ... не знаю почему данные разные, **но памяти жрет! Мама не горюй**. 

Теперь я наверное буду лучше понимать проблемы у одного заказчика.

А так, тест показал, что Си и питон для "массивных" задач просто в разных лигах.

Comment: @avp, мне кажется что разница в производительности на порядок с лихвой компенсируется тем, что нужно написать всего одну строчку и не надо отлаживать.

Comment: @alexlz, linpack (да еще если MPI) на питоне? Впервые слышу. 

Вообще-то для линпака очень важно экономно расходовать память. Реально высокие результаты (процентов 90 от теоретического максимума) получаются только на размерностях, когда память узлов кластера заполнена процентов на 85.

--

Жаль здесь комментарии кончаются (наверное последний).

--

А на домашней Ваш пример вечерком прогоню и в **update** ответа кину.

Comment: Ну и ... Насчёт rand() и randint(). rand() выдаёт значения от 0 до MAX_INT,  а randind(a, b) -- от a до b-1 (тут я немного наврал). Это в питоне range() такой.

Answer (score 2):

Не самое шустрое решение, но, все-таки: 
можно перегнать данные из массивов в списки( например a, b, c). Дальше взять самый маленький (например а) список и делать следующее:

```
ArrayList<Integer> sameNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();   
for ( int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ ){
   if ( b.contain(a.get(i)) ){
       if ( c.contain(a.get(i) ){
          sameNumbers.add(a.get(i))
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Получается у меня будет сложность алгоритма равная размеру самого маленького массива?

Comment: или это сумма размеров всех трех массивов?

Comment: нет, больше будет   
Дело в том, что на каждой итерации ты еще определяешь есть ли элемент из самого мелкого списка сначала в одном, и, если он там лежит, то проверяешь его наличие в третьем...

Comment: таки это ax * bx + bx * cx + ax * cx или ax + bx + cx
Просто мне критично сделать как максимум сложности второй вариант, а лучше меньше

Comment: нет, тут просто произведение длин массивов

Answer (score 1):

несколько простых вариантов:

```
предположим у нас на входе 3 массива A[], B[], C[] (в порядке возрастания размерности)

Вариант 1:
Сортируем все массивы. Пробегаемся по первому массиву и ищем совпадения в двух других (при происке храним индексы поиска для последних 2х массивов). Для каждого массива индекс увиличивается до тех пор пока не найдено совпадение или же элемент в массиве B (или С) больше чем элемент из массива А + нужно добавить обработку дубликатов

Вариант 2:
Аналогичный первому с той разницой что сортируется только первый массив A. При поиске элементов в массивах B, C производится сортировка до тех пор пока след элемент не будет больше чем искомый из массива А.

Вариант 3:
Во время сортировки массива А пузырьком выталкиваем самый маленький элемент и сразу делаем поиск в массивах B, C сопряженный с их сортировкой (тоже пузырьком).

p.s. в первом варианте возможна оптимизация - после сортировки мы сужаем область поиска. в каждом массиве увиличиваем нижнюю границу поиска до тех пор пока элемент меньше чем в других массивах. аналогично делаем для верхней границы.

напр:
'1 2 3 4 5 6 7' --> '2 3 4 5 6 7' --> '2 3 4 5'
'2 3 4 5 6 7'   --> '2 3 4 5 6 7  --> '2 3 4 5'
'2 3 5'         --> '2 3 5'       --> '2 3 5'

понятно что данные "обрезания" ограничиваются совпадениями в массивах или же их полным отсутствием (когда нижняя граница = верхней). если выделять совпадения и повторять действия - получим еще один алгоритм.
```

Answer (score 0):

а XOR-ом найти одинаковые элементы нельзя?

Comment: а чем это принципиально отличается от поэлементного сравнения?

Comment: это быстрее

Comment: @Beraliv, код в студию.